# Взаимное расположение трех textView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Имеется три `TextView`, размещенные в одну строку таким образом, что первый `TextView` касается левого края экрана, третий - правого края, второй находится между ними. Текст для всех трех `TextView` задается динамически. Задача - сделать текст в втором TextView по центру родителя, но при этом, если он будет слишком длинным, то не позволять ему заезжать на соседние `TextView`.

Я пробовал класть все это в `RelativeLayout`, и ставить второму `TextView` ширину `match_parent`, но тогда тексты начинают заползать друг на друга.

Еще я пробовал это делать из кода следующим образом:

```
root.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom){
            int leftWidth = txtLeft.getWidth();
            int rightWidth = txtRight.getWidth();
            int desiredWidth = rootView.getWidth() - leftWidth - rightWidth - dpToPx(20);
            if (txtHeading.getWidth() != desiredWidth) txtHeading.setWidth(desiredWidth);
        }
    });
```

Однако, в таком случае я получаю очень частые вызовы этого метода + странную запись в логи:

> requestlayout improperly called.

Подозреваю, что что-то в этом методе неверно. Есть ли способ, сделать это более элегантно?

**UPD_1:**

[image: скриншот на ответ @McDaggen]

Если текст в крайних view небольшой, а в центральном - вылезает за границы экрана, то у него не получается занять все место между крайними view

Comment: я так полагаю, вы хотели сказать что третий текст вью касается правого края?

Comment: Именно, спасибо.

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы при помещении объемного текста в центральный `TextView` чтобы пропорции оставались как и есть, однако чтобы центральный увеличивался только вниз?

Comment: Скопируйте объемный текст и задайте его для центрального `TextView` он не будет перекрывать другие `TextView`

Comment: В том то и дело, что нет. На скриншоте у центрального `TextView` стоит тег `maxLines=1` и вставлен очень большой текст, который не может влезть на экран. Мне бы хотелось, чтобы он забрал все доступное пространство у первого и третьего `TextView`, при этом не перекрывая их.

Comment: Я уже далеко от компьютера, попробуйте центральному вес увеличить до 5-7. Какова суть в длинном тексте если вы используете синглайн?

Comment: Увеличение веса приведет к тому, что первый и третий текста могут начать отображаться не полностью. Я бы объяснил это хотелкой заказчика ) К слову, даже если разрешить несколько строк текста, они все равно будут отображаться на некотором расстоянии от левого и правого контролов.

Answer (score 1):

Такую разметку можно довольно просто сверстать в новом контейнере `ConstraintLayout`. Все три виджета связываем в цепочку (chains) через свойство `layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle`, цепочке устанавливаем атрибут `Spread inside` (крайние виджеты у краев контейнера), центральному виджету устанавливаем свойство `Weighted` (занимать все доступное место, но не перекрывать другие виджеты, через указание размера по горизонтали 0dp), контенту в этом виджете устанавливаем центрирование по горизонтали, так же виджету указаны отсупы в 8dp от соседних виджетов, чтобы текст не сливался.

разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView 1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Very long text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView 3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Результат:

текст в середине короткий

[image: scrn]

текст в середине длиннее выделенного ему места (фраза повторяется три раза)

[image: scrn]

Узнать об этом [подробнее](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-chain)

Comment: Браво,  сэр! :-D

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Либо я не до конца разобрался с этим, либо это очень похоже на горизонтальный `LinearLayout` с тремя элементами. Проблема в том, что  если первый и третий текста будут отличаться по длине, то второй текст не будет по центру родительского контейнера. Есть ли способ исправить это при создании `View`, учитывая что в этот момент уже известен текст для отображения?

Answer (score 0):

Поместите ваши 3 `TextView` в `LinearLayout` с горизонтальной ориентацией, и сделайте у всех трех ширину 0, вес первого сделайте 1, вес второго 3, вес третьего 1. Также у второго `TextView` расположение текста сделайте по центру.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="9dp"
        android:text="ТЕКСТ 1"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:padding="9dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ДЛИННЫЙ ТЕКСТ"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text_three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="9dp"
        android:text="ТЕКСТ 3"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Я обновил вопрос, добавив ситуацию, в которой это решение не справляется.